# How to get the current timestamp when using 'ps' in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, unix, script, timestamp, ps

I am writing a shell script that gets all the current processes running, and pipes them into [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) to filter out the ones I need.

But I also need it to give me a timestamp, either when the `ps` occurs, or when the process was started. It doesn't matter, I just need a time. All the processes just take fractions of a second.

My command is this:

```
ps -U USERNAME -o rss=MEM,comm=CMD,pid=PID
```

I tried going like

```
ps -U USERNAME -o rss=MEM,comm=CMD,pid=PID, start=START
```

but that just gives me a time like `hh:mm:ss`. I need something more precise than this. Timestamps are ideal.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Since you need more precise time than seconds, you can either generate your own timestamp with:

```
date +%Y%m%d%H%M%s.%N
```

keep in mind that date itself takes ~.001s to run (dependent on system), so the nanoseconds may not be the right number of significant digits.

or you can look in /proc/$THIS_PID/stat using stat
to see the start time of /init we can use:

```
stat -c %x /proc/1/stat

%x   Time of last access
%X   Time of last access as seconds since Epoch
%y   Time of last modification
%Y   Time of last modification as seconds since Epoch
%z   Time of last change
%Z   Time of last change as seconds since Epoch
```

2012-03-10 12:18:45.328784363 +0800

though if the processes are *really* fast it it may be missing by the time you get to it, this would be the case for other solutions as well, but you may want to check that the file exists first

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ps -ef` this should give the start date and time